How to set up a java module to run directly (not via a .jar file) without having to specify a main class
How does one set up a java program that can be run as a module simply by doing java -m mymodule?
I know this is possible because I have seen it in, e.g., the jwebserver documentation; you can run this by doing java -m jdk.httpserver. However there doesn't seem to be any evidence in the jdk source code about specifying the 'main' class of the module at any point, neither in the module-info.java file, nor in any of the main-containing classes of the module (of which there are two, not one).
How does the module know which main-containing class to pick as the main entry point for running the module? Is there some sort of convention that's not well documented? (e.g. if a package in the module contains a class called Main.java, is this special in any way? and should there only be one Main.java file over all packages in the module?)
In https://dev.java/learn/modules/intro/ there's an example of a module run without specifying the main class in the commandline, but it just says:

To launch a modular app, run the java command with a module path and a so-called initial module - the module that contains the main method

but without clarifying how this main method (and its respective class/package) is detected or specified for the module as the specific package/class to be used as the main entry point; and there's no requirement for a module's packages to not have more than one such main-containing class.
Please note the question is not about .jar files or specifying a main class for a jar file containing a module, but for modules themselves. (https://dev.java/learn/modules/building/ has good information for specifying main classes for jar files with modules, but this is not what I'm asking here).

check the --main-class argument to the jmod command (documentation)

@user85421 thank you, this is nice to know as I haven't played with jmod yet, but it doesn't really sound any more relevant to, say, jar --main-class. What I want to know is how you can end up with a compiled module (but not packaged in any other way, e.g. as a .jar or .jmod file) that you can run directly without specifying the main class, e.g. java -m jdk.httpserver as opposed to java -m jdk.httpserver/sun.net.httpserver.simpleserver.Main

AFAIK there are four methods to specify the main class: 1) given as argument to the Java tool (java ... <main-class> or java ... <source-code-file>); 2) given as additional argument to the -m argument to the Java tool java -m <module>/<main-class> (?); 3) in the Manifest of the JAR file (not wanted); 4) in a JMOD file (not wanted)

Right! So. In case 2, what changes does one have to make to a module to make java -m <module>/<main-class> run simply as java -m <module>? This is the question being asked.

I am afraid that is point 4

There's some confusion here, possibly on my end. Would you be able to write what you mean as an answer with a minimal example that achieves running a module as above?

@user85421 are you saying that the reason I can run java -m jdk.httpserver is because there exists a jdk.httpserver.jmod file somewhere in a standard system location? (i.e. as opposed to a standard compiled module?)

I note here that it mentions jmod files are intended for compilation / linking, and cannot be launched directly. In that page, there is also an example where a .jar file allows launching in a manner that would appear to answer my question ... except there does not appear to be a jdk.httpserver.jar on my system (but there does seem to be a jdk.httpserver.jmod in the default.jre directory)

I was not saying that; I only listed the four options I know; but there is indeed a jdk.httpserver.jmod that comes with OpenJDK and it actually has a ModuleMainClass set in its module-info.class (java.base.jmod for example does not)

@user85421 indeed. Thank you, your comments pushed me down the right rabbit hole, and I managed to answer my question :)

BTW just found a 5th option while trying out the Class-file API - preview feature of Java 24 (JEP 484) -- creating the module-info.class manually (no source, no compiler) or with class file transformation to add the ModuleMainClassAttribute  (hardly usable in production code, but works withour JAR and JMOD files)

Answering own question. I found the explanation here: https://youtu.be/C5yX-elG4w0?feature=shared&t=1857
There are two ways to create something that can be launched as java -m <modulename> without specifying the main class (i.e. without having to do java -m <modulename>/<mainclass> explicitly:

The first is to create a modular jar file, where the --main-class is specified; this allows you then to run the module as java -p <jarfile>.jar -m <modulename> syntax (as an alternative to java -jar <jarfile>.jar).
However, if one inspects the default jre, there is no jdk.httpserver.jar file or similar to be found, nor are we loading one onto the module path. So this is not what is happening in the example in the question.

The second is to create your own jre environment (i.e. resulting in a 'java' command) by using jlink. This allows you to 'bake' the modules right into your runtime environment (i.e. java --list-modules will list <modulename> as one of the modules contained in the jre itself).
Modules can be provided to jlink in two ways: as normal compiled module root folders in the module path, or as .jmod files. In the latter case, one can additionally have the 'mainclass' baked into the module-info.class file contained in the .jmod file, by passing the --main-class option to the jmod command during creation of the .jmod file.
When this is the case, running java -m <modulename> via your new jre will indeed run the module baked into the jre, without that module necessarily appearing anywhere in the generated jre directory structure (not even as a .jmod file).


Since the jdk.httpserver is baked into the default jre environment (which can be confirmed by doing java --list-modules), this allows java -m jdk.httpserver to run directly. The implication here is that the java command itself was generated via a jdk.httpserver.jmod file, which specified the mainclass. We can confirm this is indeed the case by running jmod describe jdk.httpserver.jmod, which yields (among other lines) the line:
main-class sun.net.httpserver.simpleserver.Main

